# Styling issues in monorepo with Turborepo, SvelteKit and Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, monorepo, sveltekit, turborepo

I’ve created a monorepo with Turborepo that contains 2 SvelteKit apps and 2 packages: a component library (which is also based on SvelteKit) and a configuration package.

```
root
|
|- packages
|   |- component-library
|   `- config
|
`- apps
    |- app1
    `- app2
```

The *config* package contains the Tailwind and PostCSS config files, which are used in the component library and both apps.

My issue is that components imported from the *component-library* are displayed correctly in *app1* but appear to have issues with Tailwind classes in *app2*. Some classes are present but some are not. I’m using Tailwind in JIT mode.

Versions of used packages:

```
"turbo": "^1.2.4",
"svelte": "^3.34.0",
"@sveltejs/kit": "1.0.0-next.316",
"tailwindcss": "3.0.23",
```

I’m not even sure if this is because SvelteKit, but if anyone has experience with a similar Turborepo-SvelteKit-Tailwind setup I would appreciate some help.

Comment: 0
        
        
            
        This answer is not useful

    
            
                
                    
                
            

    
        Show activity on this post.



        

        


    
please could you include your `tailwind.config.js` or `tailwind.config.cjs` file content in your description.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So as it turns out *(2 months later)*, the problem was that Tailwind was installed separately in each app. You should instead install Tailwind (and PostCSS and Autoprefixer) at the **root** of the monorepo. The config files can remain in a separate package and can be imported from there.

So my root `package.json` is like this now:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.4",
    "postcss": "^8.2.15",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.4",
    "turbo": "^1.3.1"
}
```

And both `tailwind.config.cjs` files in the `app` packages are like:

```
module.exports = require('config/tailwind.config.cjs')
```

---

Also don't forget to add the paths in your **main** `tailwind.config.cjs` *(eg: `packages/config/tailwind.config.cjs`)* to the files that contain Tailwind classes.

Mine has this:

```
content: [
    '../../packages/component-library/src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts,svx}',
    './src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts,svx}'
]
```

> So this means that no matter which app is importing the config file, Tailwind should look in the `component-library` package **and** the current app source files.

Comment: Thanks for that @Adam. In my case, I only have one web app in the turbo repo so I only have one tailwind.config.js. Fortunately, you can just use relative paths for the content paths back up to the main `node_modules` folder.

Comment: [edited after 5 minutes so a new comment was needed...]

Specifically, I needed the following to use `react-daisyui`

``` 
content: [
  "./app/**/*.{ts,tsx,jsx,js}",
  "../../node_modules/daisyui/dist/**/*.{ts,tsx,jsx,js}",
  "../../node_modules/react-daisyui/dist/**/*.{ts,tsx,jsx,js}",
],
```

Comment: I'm not sure about how to connect DaisyUI with a monorepo but I don't think making Tailwind look for classes in files that are in `node-modules` is the best way.

This in the `tailwind.config.js` should be enough to make it work I **think**:

`content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'], plugins: [require('daisyui')]`

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense. tailwind is a plugin to postcss, postcss is a plugin to sveltePreprocess, and sveltePreprocess is a plugin to vite. The apps encapsulate their own vite build environments within their workspaces. tailwind, autoprefixer and postcss should be defined as dependents within the application workspaces. How did you arrive at this conclusion and why does it work?

Comment: Also relative imports in the base config isn’t ideal because it requires that you follow that folder hierarchy. And it specifies that the dependent should also be depending on the UI package. It’s best to exclude context from the base config

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I don't have to install tailwindcss-related packages in the root of monorepo.

But I have to add files of shared package (like component-library in the original question) to `tailwind.config.js`.

So in the `/apps/app1/tailwind.config.js`, below content should be added.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    ...
    content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}', '../../packages/component-library/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'],
    ...
};
```